# Count how many sentences there are in each row within a pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

I am trying to determine how many sentences there are in each row.

```
Sent

I went out for a walk.
I don't know. I think you're right!
so boring!!!
WTF?
Nothing
```

I created a list of punctuation symbols I am interested in for determining the number of sentences per each row:

```
Output 
1
2
1
1
1
```

In order to get this result, I first considered to split each row whether I met a symbol (for instance `.` or `!` or `?`). But I do not know how to get the count.

My code is

```
import re

def sentence(sent):
    return re.findall('[\w][\.!\?]', sent)

df['Sent'] = df['Sent'].apply(sentence)
```

Could you please give my advice on how to get it?

Comment: You really need to add your code to the question so we can see what format your data is, and what format the output should be.

Comment: Sorry. Added the code

Comment: well `findall` returns a list. Did you try `len(re.findall(...))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea if dont need last value like `1` use [`Series.str.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html) with regex for match letter with escaped `.!?`:

```
df['Output'] = df['Sent'].str.count('[\w][\.!\?]')
print (df)
                                  Sent  Output
0               I went out for a walk.       1
1  I don't know. I think you're right!       2
2                         so boring!!!       1
3                                 WTF?       1
4                              Nothing       0
```

If need replace `0` by `1`:

```
df['Output'] = df['Sent'].str.count('[\w][\.!\?]').clip(lower=1)
print (df)
                                  Sent  Output
0               I went out for a walk.       1
1  I don't know. I think you're right!       2
2                         so boring!!!       1
3                                 WTF?       1
4                              Nothing       1
```

Another idea is use `textstat` lib:

```
import textstat

df['Output'] = df['Sent'].apply(textstat.sentence_count)
print (df)
                                  Sent  Output
0               I went out for a walk.       1
1  I don't know. I think you're right!       2
2                         so boring!!!       1
3                                 WTF?       1
4                              Nothing       1
```